# Top down and Bottom up programming

Tags: java, c++, c

Why do we say languages such as C are top-down while OOP languages like Java or C++ are bottom-up? Does this classification have any importance in software development?

Comment: We don't say anything of the sort. Where did you get this? It is *programming styles* or even *analysis* which is top-down or bottom-up. But this topic dates from the 1970s. We are well past all that now. The 'top-down' fallacies were exposed decades ago.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The "top down" approach takes a high level definition of the problem and subdivides it into subproblems, which you then do recursively until you're down to pieces that are obvious and easy to code.  This is often associated with the "functional decomposition" style of programming, but needn't be.

In "bottom up" programming, you identify lower-level tools that you can compose to become a bigger program.

In reality, almost all programming is done with a combination of approaches.  in object oriented programming, you commonly subdivide the problem by identifying domain objects (which is a top down step), and refining those, then recombining those into the final program — a bottom up step.

Comment: No wonder I hate OO. Top-down design in practice results in unforeseen problems.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat I'm sorry it's taken so long to spot this comment. Now, that said, in general, OO isn't supposed to be practiced top-down anyway. And pretty much all programming will involve going back and reworking. That's why Fred Brooks advises "Plan to throw one away. You will anyway."

Answer (score 30):

In Top-Down development you start out with your main function, and then think of the main steps you need to take, then you break up each of those steps into their subparts, and so on.

In Bottom-Up programming you think of the basic functionality and the parts you're going to need and build them up.  You develop the actors and their methods, and then you tie them together to make a coherent whole.

OOP naturally tends toward Bottom-Up as you develop your objects, while procedural programming tends toward Top-Down as you start out with one function and slowly add to it.

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard the terms "top-down" and "bottom-up" used in that way.

The terms are usually used to describe how one approaches design and implementation of a software system and so apply to any language or programming paradigm.

In "On LISP", Paul Graham uses the term "bottom-up" slightly differently to mean continually extracting common functionality into shared functions so that you end up creating a new, higher level dialect of LISP that lets you program in terms of your application domain. That's not a common use of the term. These days we would call that "refactoring" and "domain-specific embedded languages" (and old LISP programmers would sneer that LISP has been able to do that since the 1950s).

Answer (score 6):

I've never heard that classification applied to specific languages, rather it's a programming paradigm - do you first fill out the details (i.e. build full implementation methods) and then put them together (e.g. call them from them main() method), or start with the logical flow and then flesh out the implementation?

You can really do either with both types of lanugages...  But I would say it's typically the opposite, in current OOP languages you'll first define the interfaces, forming the logical structure, and only afterwards worry about the implementation, whereas straight procedural languages like C, you need to actually implement some methods before you call them.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The question has a false statement. They are just approaches that can be respected and implemented independently from the programming language in use. With the complexity of modern software, both approaches are mixed and lot of developers use them both without even being aware of that. Your answer must be the accepted one because it is straightforward and not confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

In top-down approach the system is first formulated specifying but not detailing any subsystem at the beginning, and then each system and its subsystem is defined in great detail until specifying it to the base.

e.g.- In a C program one needs to declare functions at the top of the program and then through the main entry to every subsystem/subroutine is defined in great detail.

In bottom-up approach first designing, beginning  from the base level to the abstract level is done.

e.g.-In c++/java starts designing from class from basic level of the programming features and then goes to the main part of the program.

Answer (score 1):

It's more about paradigm (object oriented, imperative, functionnal etc.) than syntax.

From [dept-info.labri.fr](http://dept-info.labri.fr/~strandh/Teaching/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/bottom-up-programming.html)

> Bottom-up programming is the opposite of top-down programming. It
>   refers to a style of programming where an **application is constructed
>   starting with existing primitives of the programming language**, and
>   constructing gradually more and more complicated features, until the
>   all of the application has been written.

Later in the same article :

> In a language such as C or Java, bottom-up programming takes the form
>   of constructing abstract data types from primitives of the language or
>   from existing abstract data types.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe the difference between the top down approach and bottom up approach to programming is that the top down approach takes the problem and into and breaks into manageable steps and bottom up approach is actually detailing those steps.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the procedural or low level languages follow Top-down approach like C language.Similarly high level languages like java ,c++ etc follows Bottom-Up Approach.

In Top-down approach,all the system or big functions are broken down into small subsystem whereas in Bottom-up approach,Small sub-system are combined together to develop a big and final system.

e.g.Recursive is top down approach while Iterative is Bottom up approach.