# java coding:: Eclipse showing Compile time error on Line 4 only why?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    char a=true;//Line 1
    char b=null; //Line 2
    char c='\n'; //Line 3
    char d='Hell'; //Line 4
}
```

Eclipse showing Compile time error on Line 4 only why?
My understanding compiler reads top to bottom. so it should say compile time error on line number 1. but How is the priority goes to Line number 4.
Kindly clarify. Thanks

Comment: Hell is a string. A char (character) is only 1 character of code, such as your '\n'

Comment: I do understand 'Hell' is a string, so it is throwing compilation error. My question is in this code snap there is compilation error on line 1. But in Eclipse compile time error shows for Line number 4. so Why?

Comment: @user2277872, I believe the OP means that it should have said there is an error in line one, 'cause it assigns **true** to a char variable.

Comment: [May be this would help you!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881064/top-down-and-bottom-up-programming).
& [This also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966406/java-compiler-not-give-all-error-at-a-time)

Comment: I am also getting compilation error on line 1 when wrote this code in Intellij IDEA(different IDE) but not in Eclipse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. I think here at line no. 4 there is Syntax error so compiler first check    Syntax of expression so you know that this is not a right way to character    like that('Hello').
2. You saying why compiler doesn't show error on line 1 & 2 first.Its because of statement at line 1 & 2 are not wrong according to syntax.There are semantically wrong i.e. logically.

so according to me compiler first prefer syntax error of your code. I will hope you will understand it (Syntax & Semantics).

Comment: Thanks.. I got the Answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question we need to understand how java compiler works in case of a `Char` during Lexical analysis.

Ideally compiler only expects a `char` to have only one character so it scans for opening `'` and the end of it.

In the case above, it throws error as **`analyser`** flags an error stating that- it found more than one chars which results `"Unclosed Character literal"` which unfortunately happens way before compiler actually checks `casting exception` or `Type incompatibity`.

The poor `IDE` unaware of everything happening behind the scene gives it more priority.

You can get all the errors at your disposal by changing the `'` to `"`:

```
    char a=true;//Line 1
    char b=null; //Line 2
    char c='\n'; //Line 3
    char d="Hell"; //Line 4
```

As now in the above condition `Lex` is happy and moved ahead.